# What are the factors that affect search engine rankings?

Tags: seo, google, pagerank

OK, a big question, and one that I assumed had already been answered here, but it hasn't.

I'm looking for a comprehensive hierarchy of all the factors that go into determining how a search result will be positioned given a certain Google query or keyword.

I understand that the algorithm is proprietary, and we'll never know the whole truth. But what can we know for certain? What has Matt Cutts & team told us, and what have others confirmed?

Comment: tbh pagerank who cares... Its not even a major factor in today's algorithm. Pagerank used to be the algorithm and todays algorithm there is no evidence to support its used. Lots of evidence to support this how many sites with low PR outrank those with high PR.  If legitimately used then PR can show the potential of a site, but analyzing the age, backlinks using 3rd party tools is far more reliable than checking a PR rank. A lot has changed in 17 years and it's time to forget PR and focus on true factors that actually play a major role.

Comment: Entire books are written about this subject.  This is way to broad to answer in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, PageRank is not relevant anymore, you can forget it. However, the following SEO factors are relevant.

Because images are better than texts (for comprehension), here are two up-to-date images introducing SEO factors to maximize ranking of a website:

1. First one from [moz.com](http://searchengineland.com/seotable):

   [image]
2. Second one from [searchenginejournal.com](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/infographic-googles-200-ranking-factors/):

   [image]